Can't set service account properly on dataflow flex-template run
I want to overwrite the default SA used by the dataflow worker e.g default-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com that get created and used by default if you don't specify anything. ButI want my own service account and therefore add the
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "flexing" \
  --project=$(PROJECT)\
  --template-file-gcs-location=$(JSON_PATH) \
  --service-account-email=$(MY_SA) \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --parameters=source=$(MY_SOURCE) \
  --temp-location=$(TEMP_LOCATION) \
  --staging-location=$(STAGING_LOCATION)

This starts the dataflow job as expected but later down the line fails with Unable to open template file: gs://..../template_launches/..../operation_result..". As I have my image in another project I know that the default SA will fail (as it does not have artifact.reader on the other project).
Looking in log explorer this also seems to be the case as the compute.instances.insert.authenticationInfo.principalEmail = default-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com which I assume means that it falls back the the default?
The only place I find my SA is in the request.ServiceAccounts.email 
What am I doing wrong for it to fall back to the default all the time?

Or is it just me misunderstanding the role of Principalemail? if so what could my issue be

My latest theory is that I might need to add serviceAccountTokenCreator to my SA as my image is in another project and this might cause the issue, given that I'm setting my SA correctly here?

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/run#--service-account-email is the Dataflow Service Account, which should follow https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker-service-account to setup.
